# How do I determine which levels are available for a given dependency?

Tags: gradle, android-studio-3.0

I'm relatively new to Android Studio and find myself very confused about the levels for dependencies in Gradle. Let me explain why, then I am seeking assistance with a specific issue and the broader issue of choosing dependency levels. I should mention that I am using Android Studio 3.1.3 with Gradle 4.4. My Min SDK Level is 24 and my compile level is 27).

I am doing my first experiments with Settings and have skimmed several tutorials (online and in YouTube). They all begin with the advice that you need to add a dependency for Preferences in your Gradle file. (They aren't consistent in WHICH dependency to add but I think that's because there are different approaches to doing preferences.) In any case, once you've chosen which approach you are going to take, you need to add the appropriate dependency to your build.gradle (Module app) file.

So, let's say we decide to add com.android.support:preference. According to the manual - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/Preference - the current version is v7:28.0.0-alpha1. If I add that to the Gradle file though and try to sync, Android Studio tells me I should not let the dependency be a higher level than the compile SDK level (which is 27).

So, I imitated the level that I used in other dependencies, like appcompat, and set the level to v7:27.1.1 and tried to sync again. That failed too. Apparently, no such version of the dependency exists.

Most of the tutorials I've seen are two years old and refer to dependencies that are at level 24, which I assume is going to be too low.

And that brings me to my question: How do I determine which versions of a dependency actually exist so that I can choose an appropriate level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read through [this page](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/#api-versions) on the Android developer site and I suspect you may have the syntax wrong for the dependency. The `v7` should be part of the module name, not the version as I understand it.

Try:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.support.android-v7:27.1.1"
}
```

[This page](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup) makes reference to `palette-v7:27.1.1` so I assume the same version exists for `preference`.